# VirtualBox can't run Kali - "kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU"

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization, architecture

I upgraded Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 17.04. Now I installed VirtualBox and am trying to make a Kali Linux virtual machine, but it is showing me this message:

> This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.
>   Unable to boot - Please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU.

I am running Dell Optiplex 745 with 3GB Ram.

[image: VirtualBox screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

That message means your CPU is 32-bit, but the Kali image you are using is 64-bit. Use the 32-bit Kali image instead.

Comment: Dear i had tried the 32-bit image as well but it is still showing the same errot